# How can you negate this sentence?

Tags: logic

Suppose claim $P$ is "I know that I don't know you". My gut feeling says "I don't know that I don't know you". One set of lecture notes I have says I need to negate everything in the sentence in a nested fashion, which yields "I don't know that I know you". Any clarification is very much appreciated.

Comment: I think that the advise "to negate everything in the sentence in a nested fashion" refers to the way to "move inside" the negation sign of a formula... The negation of a sentence $P$ is $\lnot P$, full stop. But if $P$ is a "complex" formula, like $R \land \lnot Q$ you can start with $\lnot (R \land \lnot Q)$ and "move inside" $\lnot$ using [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to get : $\lnot R \lor Q$.

Comment: As usual when coming from natural language, the very question is how you formalize the sentence, I would say. And it seems quite hard in this case, since "I know that X" looks different from "I know X", where the last might be a relation, but what should be the first? Edit: So to give an answer I would need more information about your lecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would formalize the proposition "I know that I don't know you" in the following way: First I would introduce the relation $K(x)$ via $$K(x) :\Leftrightarrow \text{I know that x}$$ whereby $x$ is a proposition. Let $A$ be the proposition "I don't know you". So your given proposition "I know that I don't know you" is $K(A)$. The negation of $K(A)$ is $\neg K(A)$ or "I don't know that I don't know you" (as you suggested first).

The proposition "I don't know that I know you" is $\neg K (\neg A)$. Because the negation of $R(x)$ for any relation $R$ is $\neg R(x)$ not $\neg R(\neg x)$, this proposition is not the right negation. Note that $\neg x$ only make sense if $x$ itself is a proposition which is not the case for every relation $R$. So $\neg R(\neg x)$ cannot be the right negation of $R(x)$.